# Yocto: cp can't stat file: no such file or directory

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I am trying to copy two folders(containing some scripts) in my target rootfs. I have created a custom layer and a custom recipe inside it. 
 My directory structure is like this:

```
../sources/meta-company/recipes-bla_2.06/
└── bla
    ├── bla
    │   ├── dir1
    │   │   ├── dir
    │   │   │   └── files.sh
    │   └── dir2
    │       ├── dir
    │       │   ├── files.sql
    │       ├── test.sh
    └── bla_2.06.bb
```

My .bb file is as follows:

```
DESCRIPTION = " bla "

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://dir1/ \
           file://dir2/ "

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/root/dir1
    install -d ${D}/root/dir2
    cp -r --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/dir1/ ${D}/root/dir1
    cp -r --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/dir2/ ${D}/root/dir2/
}

FILE_$PN = "/root/"
```

The error I am getting:

```
> Log data follows: | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install | cp:
> cannot stat
> '/home/amol/test/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-cl-som-imx7-fsl-imx-x11/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/bla/1.0-r0/bla-1.0/dir1':
> No such file or directory | WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
> | ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at
> /home/amol/test/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-cl-som-imx7-fsl-imx-x11/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/seriald/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.49808)
> NOTE: recipe bla-1.0-r0: task do_install: Failed NOTE: Tasks Summary:
> Attempted 334 tasks of which 333 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

I am new to yocto, is my .bb file correct?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your `do_install` section,

1. `${S}` points to source directory, but `SRC_URI` copies your content in `${WORKDIR}`. So you should be using `${WORKDIR}` in your install section
2. You are trying to copy `${S}/dir1/` inside `${D}/root/dir1`, this means your final structure is `/root/dir1/dir1/`. You may not want this.

So the modified version would look like,

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/root/dir1
    install -d ${D}/root/dir2
    cp -r --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${WORKDIR}/dir1/* ${D}/root/dir1/
    cp -r --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${WORKDIR}/dir2/* ${D}/root/dir2/
}
```

Comment: Did the modification, now I am getting do_package: Files/directories were installed but not shipped.

Comment: You need `FILES_${PN} = "/root/"`

Comment: Try cleaning and recompile it`bitbake -c cleanall recipe-bla` or `-c cleansstate`